# How i can share some data from an List with two threads equally?

Tags: java, multithreading

i searched for answers from other topics but i really didn't understood much. 
What i really want is: Let's say i have some data in an ArrayList to process and two threads, (or maybe 3?). How can i make these threads get data equally (and process it)?

e.g. : for an arraylist with 10 elements and 2 threads, 5 elements for each, for an arraylist with 10 elements and 3 threads, 3 elements for each and one with 4.

Extra question: Can i specifically say THAT ONE SPECIAL thread has to start?

This is what i get from running the following code:

- Data to be processed in First processor: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- Data to be processed in Second processor:
- Data available:

(or random stuff)

What i actually want:
- Data to be processed in First processor: 0 2 4 6 8 ( or 0 1 2 3 4 )
- Data to be processed in Second processor:1 3 5 7 9 (or 5 6 7 8 9)
- Data available:

public class Data {

```
private List<Integer> dataIndex = new ArrayList<>();

Data() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dataIndex.add(i);
    }
}

public synchronized Integer extractOneData(){
    return dataIndex.remove(0);

}

public List<Integer> getDataIndex() {
    return dataIndex;
}

public void printDataIndex() {
    System.out.println("Data available:");
    for (Integer i : dataIndex) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

public class DataProcessor implements Runnable{

```
private Data data;
private String name;
private List<Integer> dataToProcess = new ArrayList<>();

DataProcessor(Data data,String name){
    this.data=data;
    this.name=name;
}

public void run(){
    while(!data.getDataIndex().isEmpty()) {
        dataToProcess.add(data.extractOneData());
    }
}

public void displaydataToProcess(){
    System.out.println("Data to be processed in " +name + ":");
    for(Integer i:dataToProcess){
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Data d = new Data();

    DataProcessor dp1 = new DataProcessor(d,"First processor");
    DataProcessor dp2 = new DataProcessor(d,"Second processor");

    Thread t1 = new Thread(dp1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(dp2);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    dp1.displaydataToProcess();
    dp2.displaydataToProcess();

    d.printDataIndex();
}
```

Comment: Why not just give each thread the data you want it to process upfront? If it's 10 things, give them five each and off you go.

Comment: There are so many different ways you could achieve these.

Comment: Can you explain your outer problem? Why do you want to divide the work equally rather than keep the threads working for the same amount of time? (There are many reasons one thread might get work done more quickly than the other, for example, if it shares a physical core with another thread.)

Comment: each thread could calculate based on the size of the list the indexes that it can work with. ex size 10, thread A works with from 0 to size/2, and second thread from (size/2) + 1 to size, now you can use this aproach to set a more complex way for even an unknown number of threads or created n threads accordingly to the size and the distribuition

Comment: The results say that the first thread is taking all the data, while the second one does nothing

Comment: So in the while method i limit the number of data each thread can extract right?

Comment: Have you looked at the `java.util.concurrent` package? It sounds like you're trying to re-invent things that already exist - such as classes that facilitate balancing a workload across multiple threads.

Comment: u can eventually use  `parallelStream()` from `java8` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

Comment: Your code has a couple of issues hence the likelihood that thread one will process all elements are rather high. First, your workload is way to tiny - copying 10 elements from a collection to a collection is almost nothing for a modern computer and thus will be processed almost immediately. Next, you expect even dividing but don't provide a mechanism to let both threads wait on a go signal (Thread one already processes items while Thread two is being started) - a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) is quite handy therefore

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For my own convenience I have made Data and DataProcessor as inner classes but you can separate them on local

```
public class ForcedMultithreading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ForcedMultithreading f = new ForcedMultithreading();

        Data d = f.new Data();

        int numberOfThreads = 2;

        int perThreadLoad = d.size() / numberOfThreads;

        DataProcessor dp1 = f.new DataProcessor(d, "First processor", perThreadLoad);
        DataProcessor dp2 = f.new DataProcessor(d, "Second processor", perThreadLoad);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(dp1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(dp2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        dp1.displaydataToProcess();
        dp2.displaydataToProcess();

        d.printDataIndex();
    }

    class Data {

        private List<Integer> dataIndex = new ArrayList<>();

        Data() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                dataIndex.add(i);
            }
        }

        public int size() {
            return dataIndex.size();
        }

        public synchronized Integer extractOneData() {
            return dataIndex.remove(0);

        }

        public List<Integer> getDataIndex() {
            return dataIndex;
        }

        public void printDataIndex() {
            System.out.println("Data available:");
            for (Integer i : dataIndex) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }

    }

    class DataProcessor implements Runnable {

        private Data data;
        private String name;
        private int perThreadLoad;
        private List<Integer> dataToProcess = new ArrayList<>();

        DataProcessor(Data data, String name, int perThreadLoad) {
            this.data = data;
            this.name = name;
            this.perThreadLoad = perThreadLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (perThreadLoad > 0) {
                dataToProcess.add(data.extractOneData());
                this.perThreadLoad--;
            }
        }

        public void displaydataToProcess() {
            System.out.println("Data to be processed in " + name + ":");
            for (Integer i : dataToProcess) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Also in the above code, the size i.e 10 is being divided by 2 i.e. two threads but you can figure out the maths in details for 'size' not exactly divisible by 'numberOfThreads' for e.g. 10 / 3

Comment: Rather than posting a code-wall (which does not work in all cases) you should explain what problems the current solution has and how these problems should be fixed

Comment: @RomanVottner I wanted to give the OP an idea to start. Didn't want to write the complete solution. Writing the list of problems was a lot to put in comments so I decided to write a code that would at least give the OP a place to start.